# Array Input java

Tags: java, arrays

I've got this problem where we are introduced to elementary error checking, and we have to specifically check that array tokens has 2 elements. if there is a problem with the format of the data then inform the user but carry on accepting input.

the inputs it will need to accept is

1. quit
2. put mark name
3. get name

The quit scenario works as before, the second scenario stores the student and their mark at the next available array index; whilst get just returns the mark of any student who matched to the name there may be more than one such student, there many be none.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b; 
        String student[] = new String [50];
        String mark [ ]= new String [50];
        int i =0;
        while ((b=s.nextLine()) != null)
        {
            if (b.equals("quit")) break ;
            String Tokens[] = b.split(b, ';');
            //System.out.println(Tokens[0] + ' ' + Tokens[1]);
            student[i]=Tokens[0];
            mark[i]=Tokens[1];
            i++;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(student[j] + ' ' + mark[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and where is your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Wow.

First:

```
String student[] = new String [50];
String mark [ ]= new String [50];
```

No. Just no. Never, ever, ever do anything like that. What happens when there are 51? If you did that during an interview, you would be escorted to the door. Suggestions:

1. Create a "Student" class that has a "name" and a "mark". Property, field, whatever.
2. Create a List of type Student. Use a data type (such as ArrayList) that grows automatically.

Second:

```
while ((b=s.nextLine()) != null)
    {
        if (b.equals("quit")) break ;
```

Why didn't you just write that as:

```
while ((b = s.nextLine()) != null && !b.equals("quit"))
    {
```

Third:

```
String Tokens[] = b.split(";");
```

Better to write the type as String[] and to use lower case for the variable (as per Java standard coding conventions); you also did not even look at the Javadoc for the split() method, so what you wrote will never work. Try:

```
String[] tokens = b.split(b, ';');
```

(You might have to escape the semi-colon; look at the doc for regular expressions.)

Finally, as to your question, you simply need to verify that the array has two elements?

```
if (tokens.length != 2) {
  // this is where you react to the formatting problem
}
```

I sure hope that this is just some introductory school project ...

Comment: sorry about that guys, the problem is how would I go about adding the things that I've listed at the top seen as I'm quite new to java i don't know much and i was hoping you lot here at stack overflow could help                                   so basically i just want to know how you'd go about getting 1 to 3 done

Comment: My advice is to read the JavaDoc for each of the things you are trying to use. For example, String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ... and also just to experiment with the code, figuring it out step by step. You will learn much that way.